# Clarification for a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

Are "why was my edit rejected" questions welcome here on meta?

If not, is there the possibility to "flag" or " ask a review" ? I think that doing again the same edit is not a good practice.

If yes, why my edit was rejected? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5199331 I just completed the menu commands to activate a functionality (the OP just skipped some steps, and the question was not about that). 
I understand if the edit is considered unimportant, but all the reject reasons are "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post"

Comment: The edit was rejected because, "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

Comment: Why it's incorrect?

Comment: Also note that editing a question that's closed and not really salvageable isn't really worth the time/effort.  The question won't be an appropriate question even after the edits.

Comment: I see from comments and reply that the main problem is the original question is off-topic. Actually I was not trying to reopen it, I landed on this question to use it as a reference and found that the instructions (unrelated to the questions) where not clear. Rather than writing on some notebook of mine I preferred correct the original source, having the possibility.

Comment: Don't edit closed posts unless your edit makes it ready for reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion: *avoid spending time trying to edit off-topic posts.*

My second suggestion: *avoid changing the meaning of questions.*  If a question is fundamentally misguided, point out the error in a comment.

Comment: Why point out error in comment instead of fixing? If asker did not came back to his question for say - two years - it's unlikely he'll come back. Edit will make the question better, won't it?

Comment: @robert-harvey What if an edit is rejected because the reviewers came to an conclusion that the meaning of the question was changed (understandable, in the circumstances), and in fact this is not the case, the reviewers didn't take the time? My most recent edit corrected a typo and without it the asker's assertion that 'this works on MVSC' is clearly incorrect. Also the central question 'I get this error when' clearly isn't changed by the edit. Do I try again with a more explicit log message?

Comment: Well, it didn't work. This time I explained in the limited space, how I could be reasonably sure it was a typo (it's quite clear from all the context that it's an unintentional error) - and it was rejected again 3-1. And this time one of the rejecters took the time to ask "how do you even know it was a typo", after I had already explained this. And suggested that it wasn't helpful because the question was 2 years old.  But clearly It's still a useful question, and it would better if didn't have a confusing ommission. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6152846

Comment: @greggo: I took care of it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, but changing CLang to clang was fluff to meet the minimum edit. Adding `[i]` to the code is the fix.

Comment: @greggo: The question is old, the OP hasn't been around for a month, and there's not enough context in the OP's code or question body to make a proper determination of intent.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't agree with you about the context and intent, but I accept your decision (FWIW I learned about this m128_f32 feature in MSVC from reading this question, which I why I think it should be corrected). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that edit reviewers are extremely weary of suggested edits that might invalidate a post.  Especially if that post is a question, because you might be accidentally "fixing" the problem that the question is about.

When reviewers see a suggestion that looks like it might invalidate a post.  It's a lot easier to reject that edit than it is to do the work to make sure that the edit is completely appropriate.

And since you're making a suggested edit that 3 or more users have to spend time to review, they are right to take the easy route and click reject.

Answer (score 1):

By changing

```
visual studio 2010 → environment → task list → tokens
```

to...

```
visual studio 2010 → tools → options → environment → task list → tokens
```

You are substantially changing the original author's post. You may be correct (I am not familiar with Visual Studio), however, these types of changes are best left to the comments section. In essence, you change is commenting on the post (i.e. "I don't think the the original auto was correct, here's what I think is correct..."), which is why your edit was marked as an attempt to comment on an existing post.

Comment: The OP is asking "how to use tokens best" (and obviously is already using them) and uses a shortcut "too short" for explaining what he is talking about. I still don't see how expanding the shrotcut changes the meaning? It's like if somebody in my question would copy and paste the test of edit just for clarifying what I am talking about: it's unnecessary but doesn't change the post. Unless the only allowed edits are orthographic typos